# Advanced Custom Fields Pro - Field type "link"not showing any values

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've inherited a Wordpress site. The client has asked me to create a new page and add it to the main navigation menu. The previous developer has created this set up for the menu:

1. Created a custom field called **Options**
2. Inside Options there are 17 fields, one of which is called Menu and has the field type **Repeater**
3. Editing the field Menu it has 6 sub-fields, one of which is called **Link** and has the type Page Link

Trying to add the new link to the main menu there is a shortcut in the admin sidebar called "Options". Clicking on this opens up a tabbed interface, one of the tabs being called "header".

Clicking on this i see the custom field Menu, with the entries of the current navigation visible.

When I add a new row, set the title to my desired menu title, select standard over drop down menu, a SELECT box appears called Link. However it has no values to select. The other menu items only have one value for each.

My question is this: How can I get my new page to show in this dropdown so i can add it to the main menu? My new page is published and not a draft.

Thanks

Comment: Could you export your ACF fields and attach it here?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: There you go https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/import-export-fields-groups/ 

Use the JSON option.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the delay. Here's a link to the json file, don't see anything. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f90lwj3af1ujgw/acf-export-2020-04-11.json?dl=0